# Persist menu tree state across views - ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-state

I have this menu that I want to make available on my layout (essentially every view on my site). I want to maintain the menu's state (whether or not tree items are opened or closed) across page requests. What I want to do is possibly have a child action that is called from my layout page that grabs some cookie or session info which contains the tree's state information so I can rebuild the tree exactly how it was the last request. My problem is, from what I read, it's bad practice to call things like Session and Cookie from within ones controller actions. What I'd like to know is what's a more elegant way to solve this problem. If I must use Cookie and Session, anyone has ideas on how to mock them? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is, from what I read, it's bad practice to call things like
>   Session and Cookie from within ones controller actions

Interesting. And did the author of this article explain why it would be a bad practice? There's nothing wrong accessing the session and cookies from your controller actions. Actually using the session for this kind of things might not be suitable because if the user closes his browser you will not be able to persist the layout of the tree whereas with persistent cookies that would be possible.

Comment: Thanks. I remember the reason was unit testing. Sort of the same way it was better to use model binding in controller actions instead of access the FormsCollection directly. The problem is I'm using a child action on the layout so I'm not sure if modelbinding is an option.

Answer (score 0):

We can have the Menu as a Partial View.

The Action to Render Partial view will accept parameters to render the state.
Each link will invoke the action with different parameters.

for Example,

```
public PartialViewResult RenderNavigation(int Menuroot, int subMenuItem)
{
IList<MyNavigationItem> navigationItems=GetNavigation();// Some method that'll read nvigationitems.
navigationItems.Where(n=> n.menuId.Equals(Menuroot) ||n.IsOpen.Equals(subMenuItem)).ToList().ForEach(i=> i.IsOpen=true);

return View("SomeMenuView",navigationItems);
}

public class MyNavigationItem{
int menuId{get;set;}
bool IsOpen{get;set;}
int parentMenuId{get;set;} // set default -1 for Root Items
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So how exactly would you persist the menu from request to request?

Comment: Dont go via request to request. Better think this as page to page. For each page menu is different. partial view can be invoked in each page with different parameters.

Comment: So the parameters would come from where? Querystring? Session?

Comment: i would prefer Querystring over session. As querystring approach will be stateless behavior. A same url will results a same view irrespective of session. But If you want to go for session then Cookies will be better then Serverside sessions.